# Problem with column name reactivity in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I'm developing an Rshiny dashboard that allows upload of a csv file for heatmap visualisation. The file has the first column name as COL1, and the other columns are ID names from which a user is allowed to select. Some code in the server section use R table() to summarise two columns from the file like this: table(COL1, selected column) to arrive at nrow(30) by cols(4). This matrix is then used by a heatmap function. I can see the heatmap output and selecting different ID, however, does not change the heatmap pattern to reflect different data for each selected ID. Each time I select a different ID, I get the same heatmap. I'm guessing, ID selection is not being updated as expected. Any solution to this problem will be appreciated.

Code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("plot"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("Sidebar panel",
                 # Input: Selector for choosing dataset ----
                 fileInput("file1", "Add File",
                           accept = c(
                             "text/csv",
                             "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                              ".csv")
                 ),
                 tags$hr(),
                 checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
                 selectInput("IDs", "Add ID:", choices=c())
                 # actionButton('getHmap', 'get heatmap')
    ),
    mainPanel("Plot",
              #column(6, 
              plotOutput("themap"),
              #tableOutput("table.output")
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  data1 <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$file1,""))
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    tbl <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
    return(tbl)    
  })


  plotdata <- reactive({
   data2 <- data1()

     updateSelectInput(session,"IDs",choices=colnames(data2[,-1])) 

    data3 <- table(data2$COL1,data2[,input$sampleIDs])
    data3  <- as.data.frame.matrix(data3)
    data3  <- data3[c(2,1,4,3)]
    data4 <- data3
    data4$COL2 <- rownames(data3)
    data4 <- data4[, c(5,1:4)]
    data5 <- data4[,-1]
    data.df <- as.matrix(data5)

    return(data.df)    
  })

  output$themap = renderPlot({

    pheatmap(plotdata())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think you'd better update the selectInput right after loading the data (in between read_tbl and return)

Comment: Thanks @HubertL . I'm not sure how to implement the "update selectinput" in the position you mentioned. Do you mind helping with that pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your sertver function that way:

```
server = function(input, output, session) {

  data1 <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$file1,""))
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    tbl <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
    updateSelectInput(session,"IDs",choices=colnames(tbl[,-1])) 
    return(tbl)    
  })


  plotdata <- reactive({
    data2 <- data1()    
    data3 <- table(data2$COL1,data2[,input$sampleIDs])
    data3  <- as.data.frame.matrix(data3)
    data3  <- data3[c(2,1,4,3)]
    data4 <- data3
    data4$COL2 <- rownames(data3)
    data4 <- data4[, c(5,1:4)]
    data5 <- data4[,-1]
    data.df <- as.matrix(data5)

    return(data.df)    
  })

  output$themap = renderPlot({
    pheatmap(plotdata())
  })
}
```